# Recorrer un datatable jquery para insertar en MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

hola compañeros como puedo hacer para recorrer los rows de un datatable para luego insertarlos en una table detalle, la idea es poder hacer una especie factura que cuando se ingresen los productos, estos se listen en el datatable jquery  y luego insertar esos registros en una tabla detalle en la base de datos Mysql

soy nuevo en programación actualmente estoy intentando hacerlo con php javascript y mysql, agradezco mucho alguna guía por donde comenzar muchas Gracias de Antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas has tenido? Muestra un [repro]. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Yo hago algo muy similar, tengo un datatable con informacion, extraigo la informacion del datatable para posteriormente subirlo a una base de datos, y lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
var tblObj = $('#tblIC').DataTable();
```

Declaro mi data table, y de la siguente forma extraigo los datos de ella

```
JSON.stringify(tblObj.rows().data().toArray())
```

Te dejo la documentación del datatable por si te quedan dudas [Documentación row-data datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data())

```
 var tblObj = $('#mytabla').DataTable();
            __doPostBack("<%= lnbExportarH.UniqueID %>", 
            JSON.stringify(tblObj.rows().data().toArray()));
```

Donde lnbExportarH.UniqueID es la función que recibe la información y crea el Excel, y el otro parámetro es la información de la tabla, informacion acerca de postback aca: [Doc PostBack](https://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1521-How-call-Postback-from-Javascript.aspx)

Comment: Gracias voy a probar de esa manera

Comment: hola David, muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero estuve intentando realizar como tu dices , pero honestamente no lo logre serias tan amable de expoliarme como se debe proceder por que  la hora de hacerlo mi data table me arroja error

Comment: Se me olvido mencionar que lo hice con la funcion de javascript _doPostBack()... en donde le paso la infirmacion de un datatable a c# para crear un excel.. te recomiendo que leas algo acerca de _doPostBack()... para ver si te sirve, saludos